# How to make css class mapping

Tags: css, google-closure-stylesheet

Can anybody help me to explain more details about how to use closure stylesheet.

I want renaming my css class become more simple

For example I have a css file

```
.long-class {
      font-weight : bold;
      color : red;
}
.another-class .and-long {
      background-color : #FFFFF;
}
```

become more simple like this

```
.a-b {
      font-weight : bold;
      color : red;
}
.c-b .d-a {
      background-color : #FFFFF;
}
```

I have read this [doc](http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/#Renaming), but I didn't find the [doc](http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/#Renaming) very clear on that.

Thanks...

Comment: How is that 'more simple'? Your class-names are now pretty meaningless, so it'll cost more time trying to work out what elements you're actually styling every time you edit your stylesheet.

Comment: I mean 'more simple' here is also for reduced the size of the CSS that is sent down to users. By using closure stylesheet it's mean that I want rename my class automatically but I didn't find the doc very clear to explain about the step.

Comment: why are you looking to change your rules? that would be a total mess when it comes to rediting your file later, if you wanna reduce your css file just use any minify tool out there, http://www.cssminifier.com/, now if you want to change all your css files with 3-easy-steps use your find and replace tool on your code editor

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use http://lesscss.org/